# Mass CSV import and combine in Rstudio

Tags: r, csv

I'm downloading files from a HOBOware logger and the CSV that it produces is messy. I need to remove columns 1, 5-8, and skip the first line.

There's a lot of files and I'm trying to upload them at once, but the skip line is giving me issues

Thanks to another thread I can almost do what I want, but the one blank row in the CSV is causing the data to not upload correctly creating blank cells

This I the code that works when reading each CSV individually

```
library(readr)
Pool_620180212 <- read_csv("Pool 6/Pool_620180212.csv", 
    col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")), 
    skip = 1)
```

So I thought I could get past it by doing the following

```
setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/NEW R/Converted HOBO files")
mydir = "Pool 6"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, Skip = 1)
```

I don't know how to format the argument to incluse the following formatting for each CSV to be able to read correctly

```
"col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")), 
    skip = 1)"
```

I'm not too experienced with R so any suggestions for removing the unneeded columns would be great too, I've been doing this for each column which is very cumbersome

```
file$column = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/NEW R/Converted HOBO files")
x = lapply(list.files(pattern="*\\.csv"), function(x){
  fread(x) 
})%>% rbindlist()
```

You can remove the column after the loop.

Or specify it within the loop:
I am unsure what your columns are, but it would look like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/NEW R/Converted HOBO files")
x = lapply(list.files(pattern="*\\.csv"), function(x){
  fread(x) 
x$date = ymd_hms(x$date)
x$col = NULL
})%>% rbindlist()
```

Comment: "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pbapply’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3"

Comment: hmm that's weird.  You can substitute pblapply with lapply from base r.  pblapply allows you to see the progress of your loop.

Comment: @Chris, please check my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Also not compatible with my version of R for some reason

Comment: lapply is part of base r.  There's no need to load it in. I'll edit my answer to avoid pblapply.

Comment: Lapply is no longer used in recent versions of R

Comment: make sure you're using ```lapply()``` and not Lapply.